# find angle between major axis of ellipse and x-axis of coordinate (help me implement method from paper)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

So I am trying to implement a method from this [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s42452-019-0786-8). I am stuck at the part where I have to find the angle between the major axis of the lesion’s best-fit ellipse and the x-axis of the coordinate system.

Here is the sample image:

[image]

Here is what I got so far:

[image]

Is it possible to find that angle? And after the angle has been found, I have to flip the RoI along x-axis by the angle.

**UPDATE ----------**

Google drive link to Roi Image: [RoI image](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vAUtbsJE30C9qqr-eLmSygc9GQ_bxIIG?usp=sharing)

Implementing method step by step based on the [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s42452-019-0786-8).

**First**, I should recenter the RoI to the center of the image coordinate. In the paper, they centered the RoI using its centroid. I manage to do it based on this code I found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60925526/5285174). The result is fine if my RoI is small and not touching the image border. But if I have large image the result is really bad. So I ended up centering the RoI using boundingRect. Here is the result of centering:

[image]

Code for centering RoI:

```
import math

import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# read image
cont_img = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\Pandu\Desktop\IMD064_lesion.bmp", 0)
cont_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(cont_img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)

# fit ellipse and find ellipse properties
hh, ww = cont_img.shape
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(cont_img, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(contours[0])
(xc, yc), (d1, d2), angle = ellipse

# centering by centroid
half_width = int(ww/2)
half_height = int(hh/2)
offset_x = (half_width-xc)
offset_y = (half_height-yc)

T = np.float32([[1, 0, offset_x], [0, 1, offset_y]])
centered_by_centroid = cv2.warpAffine(cont_img.copy(), T, (ww, hh))
plt.imshow(centered_by_centroid, cmap=plt.cm.gray)

# centering by boundingRect
# This centered RoI is (L)
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[0])
startx = (ww - w)//2
starty = (hh - h)//2
centered_by_boundingRect = np.zeros_like(cont_img)
centered_by_boundingRect[starty:starty+h, startx:startx+w] = cont_img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
plt.imshow(centered_by_boundingRect, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

**Second**, after centering the RoI, I should find the orientation angel and rotate the RoI based on that angel and then flip . Using code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9042907/5285174). (is this the correct way to rotate the RoI?):

```
# find ellipse properties of centered RoI
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(centered_by_boundingRect, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(contours[0])
(xc, yc), (d1, d2), angle = ellipse
roi_centroid = (xc, yc)

rot_angle = 90 - angle
if rot_angle < 0:
    rot_angle += 180

# This rotated RoI is (Lx)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(roi_centroid, -rot_angle, 1.0)
rot_im = cv2.warpAffine(centered_by_boundingRect, M, (ww, hh))
plt.imshow(rot_im, cmap=plt.cm.gray)

# (Ly)
# by passing 0 to flip() should flip image around x-axis, but I get the same result as the paper
res_flip_y = cv2.flip(rot_im.copy(), 0)
plt.imshow(res_flip_y , cmap=plt.cm.gray)

# (L) (xor) (Lx)
res_x_xor = cv2.bitwise_xor(centered_by_boundingRect, rot_im)
plt.imshow(res_x_xor, cmap=plt.cm.gray)

# (L) (xor) (Ly)
res_y_xor = cv2.bitwise_xor(centered_by_boundingRect, res_flip_x)
plt.imshow(res_y_xor, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

I still can't get the same result as the paper, the rotating operation also produce bad result on large RoI. Help...

**UPDATE ---------- 20/03/2021**

Small RoI: fine result on rotation and looks similar with the paper, but still not getting the same end result on the L (xor) Lx or L (xor) Ly

[image]

Large RoI: bad result on rotation as the RoI get out of border/image

[image]

Comment: what do you mean that the rotating operation produces a bad result? can you post a picture on what you expect to see? It seems to be rotating just fine to me.

Comment: @Ian thank you so much for responding... question description updated...

Comment: If the issue is that the white blob is sticking out from the edges of the image, you can add a black border on the image so that it's big enough to fit the blob when it's rotated. You can add borders using cv2.copyMakeBorder()

Answer (score 2):

The angle you're looking for is returned from fitEllipse. It's just rotated a bit according to a different reference frame. You can get your counter-clockwise rotation angle by doing 90 - angle. As for rotating the roi you can either use minAreaRect to get a minimum-fit rectangle directly, or you can fit a bounding box to the contour and rotate each point individually.

The green rectangle is the minAreaRect(), the red rectangle is the boundingRect() after it's been rotated.
[image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

# rotate point
def rotate2D(point, deg):
    rads = math.radians(deg);
    x, y = point;
    rcos = math.cos(rads);
    rsin = math.sin(rads);
    rx = x * rcos - y * rsin;
    ry = x * rsin + y * rcos;
    rx = round(rx);
    ry = round(ry);
    point[0] = rx;
    point[1] = ry;

# translate point
def translate2D(src, target, sign):
    tx, ty = target;
    src[0] += tx * sign;
    src[1] += ty * sign;

# read image
cont_img = cv2.imread("blob.png", 0)
cont_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(cont_img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)

# find contour
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(cont_img, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# fit ellipse and get ellipse properties
ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(contours[0])
(xc, yc), (d1, d2), angle = ellipse

# -------- NEW STUFF IN HERE --------------
# calculate counter-clockwise angle relative to x-axis
rot_angle = 90 - angle;
if rot_angle < 0:
    rot_angle += 180;
print(rot_angle);

# if you want a rotated ROI I would recommend using minAreaRect rather than rotating a different rectangle
# fit a minrect to the image # this is taken directly from OpenCV's tutorials
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[0]);
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect);
box = np.int0(box);
cv2.drawContours(cont_rgb, [box], 0, (0,255,0), 2);

# but if you really want to use a different rectangle and rotate it, here's how to do it
# create rectangle
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[0]);
rect = [];
rect.append([x,y]);
rect.append([x+w,y]);
rect.append([x+w,y+h]);
rect.append([x,y+h]);

# rotate it
rotated_rect = [];
center = [x + w/2, y + h/2];
for point in rect:
    # for each point, center -> rotate -> uncenter
    translate2D(point, center, -1);
    rotate2D(point, 90 - rot_angle); # "90 - angle" is because rotation goes clockwise
    translate2D(point, center, 1);
    rotated_rect.append([point]);
rotated_rect = np.array(rotated_rect);
cv2.drawContours(cont_rgb, [rotated_rect.astype(int)], -1, (0,0,255), 2);
# ------------- END OF NEW STUFF -----------------


# draw fitted ellipse and centroid
target_ellipse = cv2.ellipse(cont_rgb.copy(), ellipse, (37, 99, 235), 10)
centroid = cv2.circle(target_ellipse.copy(), (int(xc), int(yc)), 20, (250, 204, 21), -1)

# draw major axis
rmajor = max(d1, d2)/2

if angle > 90:
    angle = angle - 90
else:
    angle = angle + 90

xtop_major = xc + math.cos(math.radians(angle))*rmajor
ytop_major = yc + math.sin(math.radians(angle))*rmajor
xbot_major = xc + math.cos(math.radians(angle+180))*rmajor
ybot_major = yc + math.sin(math.radians(angle+180))*rmajor
top_major = (int(xtop_major), int(ytop_major))
bot_major = (int(xbot_major), int(ybot_major))

target_major_axis = cv2.line(centroid.copy(),
                             top_major, bot_major,
                             (0, 255, 255), 5)

## image center coordinate
hh, ww = target_major_axis.shape[:2];
x_center_start = (0, int(hh/2))
x_center_end = (int(ww), int(hh/2))
y_center_start = (int(ww/2), 0)
y_center_end = (int(ww/2), int(hh))
img_x_middle_coor = cv2.line(target_major_axis.copy(), x_center_start, x_center_end, (219, 39, 119), 10)
img_y_middle_coor = cv2.line(img_x_middle_coor.copy(), y_center_start,
                             y_center_end, (190, 242, 100), 10)

# show
cv2.imshow("image", img_y_middle_coor);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

For the future: check that your code runs before pasting it on here. Aside from the missing "import" lines it was also missing this line:

```
hh, ww = target_major_axis.shape[:2]
```

If the sample code you paste has errors, then everyone who wants to help will have to waste some time bug-stomping before they can begin working on a solution.

Comment: Hello sir @Ian Chu, thank you so much for your help and I am sorry for the missing code. I am still having trouble rotating the RoI and I still can not get the same end result as the paper. Can you please kindly check my updated question... really need some help here :(