# How to find the xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax of a mask

Tags: python, pytorch, image-segmentation, tensor

I have a mask drawn over an apple using segmentation. The mask layer has 1's where the pixel is part of the apple and 0's everywhere else. How do i find the extreme pixels in the mask to find the bounding box coordinates around this mask? I am using pytorch and yolact edge to perform the segmentation as shown in [Yolact](https://github.com/haotian-liu/yolact_edge)

Comment: is `(mask == 1)` what you are looking for?

Comment: @AerysS I am trying ot use torch.where but the issue is, How do I find the extreme left , right, top and bottom pixels of the mask (basically xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax). This returns all the ixels where the value is 1 right? How do i then find the extremes?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly then there will never always be exactly one "extreme" pixel in any direction. Imagine an arc drawn with its center as one of the image's corner, all points on this arc will be equidistance from the corner, and thus all "extreme". The best you can do is to `np.where(pixels == 1)` and then `np.min`/`np.max` over the `[0:,]` and `[1:,]` dimensions of `where` to find this possible set of "extremes" in each direction. Then figure out the most meaningful way to select one for you problem instance.

Comment: I'd image your drawing a bounding box around the mask, so selection of the possible extremes should be easy because you're either drawing a vertical or horizontal line at each "extreme" point to enclose the entire mask. Thus any point from the possible should work to provide the vertical or horizontal location of the line for the given edge of the bounding box.

Answer (score 1):

Relevant [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31402351/16398170) with nice explanation.

**TL;DR**
Proposed code snippets (second is faster):

```
def bbox1(img):
    a = np.where(img != 0)
    bbox = np.min(a[0]), np.max(a[0]), np.min(a[1]), np.max(a[1])
    return bbox

def bbox2(img):
    rows = np.any(img, axis=1)
    cols = np.any(img, axis=0)
    rmin, rmax = np.where(rows)[0][[0, -1]]
    cmin, cmax = np.where(cols)[0][[0, -1]]

    return rmin, rmax, cmin, cmax
```

But in more **general case** (e.g. if you have more than one "instance" on image and each mask is separated from others)  it may be worth to consider using OpenCV.
Specifically `cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats`.
Some brilliant description of this function can be found in another relevant [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35854198).

```
num_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(mask)
```

> **Labels** is a matrix the size of the input image where each element has a value equal to its label.
>
> **Stats** is a matrix of the stats that the function calculates. It has a length equal to the number of labels and a width equal to the
> number of stats. It can be used with the OpenCV documentation for it:
>
> > Statistics output for each label, including the background label, see
> > below for available statistics. Statistics are accessed via
> > **stats[label, COLUMN]** where available columns are defined below.
> >
> > - **cv2.CC_STAT_LEFT** The leftmost (x) coordinate which is the inclusive start of the bounding box in the horizontal direction.
> > - **cv2.CC_STAT_TOP** The topmost (y) coordinate which is the inclusive start of the bounding box in the vertical direction.
> > - **cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH** The horizontal size of the bounding box
> > - **cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT** The vertical size of the bounding box
> > - **cv2.CC_STAT_AREA** The total area (in pixels) of the connected component
>
> **Centroids** is a matrix with the x and y locations of each centroid. The row in this matrix corresponds to the label number.

So, basically each item in `stats` (first 4 values) determine the bounding box of each connected component (instance) in mask.

Possible function that you can use to return just bounding boxes:

```
def get_bounding_boxes(mask, min_size=None):
    num_components, labeled_image, bboxes, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(image)
    # return bboxes in cv2 format [x, y, w, h] without background bbox and component size
    return bboxes[1:, :-1]  
# (x, y, x+w, y+h) are 4 points that you are looking for
```

And of course in case of one instance this approach still works.