# How do I crop an image based on custom mask

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, image-processing, crop

I start my model and get a mask prediction of the area I would like to crop.

```
img = cv2.imread('picture.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224))
print(img.shape)
T = np.zeros((1, 224, 224, 3), dtype='float32')
T[0]=img
prediction = model.predict(T , verbose=1)
prediction = prediction[0, :, : , :]
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
print(prediction.shape)
plt.imshow(np.squeeze(prediction).astype(np.float32))
plt.show()
```

[image]

This code is the closest I have gotten to the desired image,
the problem with this image that is provided is that it doesn't crop out black background

```
result = prediction * img
plt.imshow((result/255).astype(np.float32))
plt.show()
```

[image]

My desired image should be like this
[image]

Comment: what do you expect, instead of blackness? that is exactly how multiplication works.

Comment: so you want it *cropped* closely? okay, call `boundingRect`, on the mask `prediction > 0.5` (assuming it's scaled like that), then take these values and do a numpy slice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
prediction = np.squeeze(prediction).astype(np.float32)
threshold = 0.5
xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = (-1,-1,-1,-1)
for j in range(224):
    for i in range(224):
        if prediction[j,i] <= threshold: continue
        xmin = i if xmin == -1 or xmin > i else xmin
        xmax = i if xmax == -1 or xmax < i else xmax
        ymin = j if ymin == -1 or ymin > j else ymin
        ymax = j if ymax == -1 or ymax < j else ymax
cropImg = img[ymin:ymax,xmin:xmax]
```

Comment: The output is same as plt.imshow(img) plt.show()

Comment: You could modify the `threshold` value in order to get the wanted bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find the bounding box around your predicted mask and then crop your image using the detected bounding box. Using the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31402351/19249364) excellent SO answer, it would result in something like this:

```py
def bbox2(img):
    # from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31402351/19249364
    rows = np.any(img, axis=1)
    cols = np.any(img, axis=0)
    rmin, rmax = np.where(rows)[0][[0, -1]]
    cmin, cmax = np.where(cols)[0][[0, -1]]
    return rmin, rmax, cmin, cmax

bbox = bbox2(prediction.squeeze())
cropped = img[bbox[0]:bbox[1]+1, bbox[2]:bbox[3]+1, :]
```

Couldn't test this code, so just tell me if it doesn't work!

Comment: The output image is same as plt.imshow(img), but my problem is solved with code above,than you for your help.